# Problem when creating a symbolic link on my server: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

Here is the problem:

```
tony@bootsy/var/www/bandop $ ln -nfs /var/www/bandop/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/bandop/releases/20090601055013/config/database.yml
ln: creating symbolic link `/var/www/bandop/releases/20090601055013/config/database.yml': No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why '/var/www/bandop/releases/20090601055013/config/database.yml' has to exist.  I want to *create* that sym link to hit the target specified above (first parameter).  The command also failed to execute when logged in as root so it does not seem to be a permissions issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path

```
/var/www/bandop/releases/20090601055013/config/
```

does not exist

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir -p /var/www/bandop/releases/20090601055013/config/`